# How to disable HTMLReportGenarator in smooks

Tags: freemarker, smooks

Currently i am doing performance testing for Smooks and c# code.Smooks performing
good only for higher MB files compare to c# code.For lower MB files its running time almost same for both smooks & c# code.
 So i browse regarding this to increase the performance of smooks for lower MB files I got to know that we need to disable the  HTMLReportGenarator in smooks.
someone please help in this case.Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Pandiyan M

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `HTMLReportGenerator` in production code acorrding to [smooks guide](http://www.smooks.org/guide):

> Only use the HTMLReportGenerator in development. When enabled, the HTMLReportGenerator incurs a significant performance overhead and with large message, can even result in OutOfMemory exceptions.

Remove from your code similar `HtmlReportGenerator` as `EventListener`:

> ```
> execContext.setEventListener(new HtmlReportGenerator("/tmp/smooks-report.html"));
> ```